# Remove double vertices for multiple objects at once

Tags: uv, workflow, objects

I'm using cell fracture to cut a model into a lot of objects and need to uv map the insides of the faces correctly onto the same UV map as the outside faces.
By using a UV project modifier for the inside faces, the inside faces are unwrapped, but in a separate UV map.

I need to export it to unity3d, which only uses 1 uv map, so I need to copy the UV coordinates in the inside map to the outside map.

I found some ways that would get me close, but I need to do some operations by hand for each object, which takes too much time.

I could join the all the objects, but then I would need to separate each piece one by one, as cell fracture also splits edges, meaning I cannot use <kbd>P</kbd>*> by loose parts* to split all the pieces back into individual objects.

If I could remove double vertices and make the inside faces and outside faces for each piece connected, I would be able to separate by loose parts after I joined and unwrapped, so is there a way to do this for multiple objects all at once?

Is there a way in blender to repeat a certain action (e.g. remove doubles) on multiple objects?

Comment: If I follow you correctly, couldn't you merge double vertices after joining everything into one object?

Comment: Also you can disable the edge splitting behavior of cell fracture, would that work? Or maybe you could use one of blenders built in scripted unwrapping methods?

Comment: As I mentioned above, if I merge everything into one object I would need to manually separate each piece, which will take a lot of time.

Comment: But by disabling the edge splitting behavior of cell fracture, I could actually merge all the pieces and use separate->by loose parts now, no need to separate each piece after copied the uvs...
Thanks a lot gandalf3 :)

Comment: this is probably a dumb question but how do I mark your response as answer here?

Comment: I have to add a proper answer first, I'll do that in a second..

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the edge splitting behavior of cell fracture:

[image]

Or if you don't want to re-fracture your object, you could join all the objects and then remove doubles. This way the split edges should be re-joined, and separate by loose parts should result in the same objects as before the join.